# «На Рождество» или «в Рождество»?

Tags: предлоги

Похоже, что *Рождество* можно употреблять и с предлогом «в», и с предлогом «на», по крайней мере, есть примеры обоих употреблений:

> Один раз, тоже на рождество, я засадила в ногу кривую занозищу и пряталась с ней по углам, и никого даже близко не подпускала.

(Харпер Ли, *Убить пересмешника…* в переводе Н. Галь и Р. Облонской.)

> — Вы, наверное, слишком заняты в Рождество, — быстро произнесла Мерль.

(Патриция Корнуэлл, *Чёрная метка*.)

Мой вопрос состоит в следующем: точно ли «в Рождество» и «на Рождество» обозначают одно и то же?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Предлог **"в"** означает, что что-либо происходит **строго между началом и концом** праздничного (или какого-либо особого) дня.

```
В праздники я был дома.
В выходные мы ездили загород.
В День Победы ветераны надевают ордена и проходят по улицам.
```

Предлог **"на"** перед названием праздника означает, что что-либо происходит **приблизительно во время праздника** (чуть раньше, чуть позже или начинается немного раньше и кончается немного позже) **и приурочено к нему**. Поэтому подарки мы получаем на Рождество (это может быть и раньше и позже Рождества, но связано с ним по смыслу).

```
На Рождество мы уезжаем в отпуск. 
На праздники мы собираемся поехать к друзьям.
Получать подарки на Пасху/Рождество/Восьмое марта очень приятно.
```

Я не согласен с уважаемым shabunc, что есть заметная разница между религиозными и светскими праздниками, и **в** используется только с религиозными. **В** перед праздниками, называющимися по дате, (восьмое марта, первое мая) не употребляется поскольку в русском языке не принято ставить предлог **в** перед датой, и даже когда дата - это название праздника, это все равно режет слух.

Похожая ситуация с Новым Годом. **В Новый Год** обычно не говорят из-за того, что слово **год** само по себе означает промежуток времени и вызвало бы двусмысленность.

Comment: +1. Добавлю, что разница "в праздники" и "на праздники" примерно как в 'in holidays' and 'at holidays'.

Comment: Разница всё-таки есть: "В 8 марта" не говорят, "в 23 февраля не говорят".

Comment: "В Хэллоуин", например, или "в Ивана Купалу" или в любое другое словосочетание без слова день - тоже звучит не так естественно, как "В Рождество" или "В Пасху".

Comment: @shabunc Если я правильно понял вопрос Olga: «точно ли "в Рождество" и "на Рождество" обозначают одно и то же?», мы обсуждаем не применимость в/на для построения произвольной фразы, а разницу смыслов "в" и "на" там, где применимы оба варианта.

Comment: я отметил, что как правило, чаще всего оба варианта применимы, когда речь идёт о религиозных праздниках - @farfareast со мной не согласился, я привёл несколько примеров, пытаясб объяснить, что я имел ввиду.

Answer (score 1):

Не всегда. Напишу по примеру Нового Года, так как мне этот праздник созвучнее, но логика та же.

> Я хочу получить НА Новый Год новые духи.

"В Новый Год" не говорят.
И еще.

> Мы поехали отдыхать на Мальдивы НА Новый Год.

В данном случае - на промежуток времени (на период праздников).

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, и примеры с предлогом "в".

Comment: @Olga Мне кажется, что если кто-то скажет "В Новый Год я хотел бы...", то это прозвучит скорее как "В Новом году", т.е. не на сам праздник, а в течение следующего года, например "Хочу пожелать вам в Новом году больше радости и смеха".

Answer (score 0):

Обычно употребляется форма `на`, когда:

- Речь идёт о конкретном намерении, связанном с личными планами и приуроченным к какому-то конкретному празднику: "На Рождество съезжу, пожалуй, в Чехию".
- Речь идёт о некоем контексте, в принципе ассоциируемом с этим праздником: "На Рождество наряжают елку.

Обычно употребляется форма `в`, когда:

- Речь идёт о событии, которое в происходит в настоящее время (или произойдёт в самое ближайшее время): "В эту Пасху хочу пожелать нам всем..."
- Речь идёт о каком-то конкретном празднике, происходящем в определённое время в определённом месте, а не о празднике вообще: "Синоптики обещают, что в Сочельник будет относительно тепло".

В целом же стоит заметить, что равноправное сосуществование этих двух форм в больше мере специфично для религиозных (не обязательно христианских) праздников, и даже в терминологии употребляемой в полупрофессиональной теологической периодике ,например, в СМИ, ориентированных на освещение религиозной тематики,  эти формы часто взаимозаменямы - например, в словосочетание `богослужение в` и `богослужение на`.

И ещё замечу, что я речь идёт о фактической практике частоты употребления первой или второй форм в современном русском. В принципе, практически во всех  (кроме, пожалуй, упомянутого уважаемым AliCruise случая) приведённых случаях, вполне допустимо применение `на`  вместо `в` и наоборот.

==============

Talking about holidays in general, first thing we should mention is that the `на` form is the only acceptable one in the overwhelming majority of cases: `На Первомай`, but (practically) never "в Первомай". So, there is a very limited number of religious holidays, and Christmas is among them, that can be used with `в` form, e. g. `Рождество`, `Пасха`, `Сочельник`, `Рамадан` and so on.

As for this holidays, even in semiprofessional theological texts, such like one can find in articles from religion news portals, terms like `Богослужение на Рождество` and `богослужение в Рождество` are used in relatively equal proportions. Yet, there is indeed a subtle difference between these two forms.

When you are talking about event that is already happening, or supposed to happen very soon, you should use `в` form:
  - В [эту] Пасху я желаю тебе, друг , всего самого хорошего.
  - В [это] Рождество желаю нам всем счастья.

When you are talking about something related to some holiday/festival that happens on a regular basis, you most probably should use "На Рождество":

- На Пасху [освящается артос](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B0) — квасной хлеб особого освящения.
- На Новый год мы стараемся уехать на дачу.
- На Рождество приходится большая часть продаж.
- Специального блюда, которое готовится на Рамадан, нет.

The mnemonic formula we can construct here is "На [какой-то праздник] [обычно принято]".

When you are talking about some personal plans that your are  going to fulfil on some certain day, you, once again, should use `на`:
  - Махнём-ка мы на Рождество к деду!

At last, when you are talking about some event, which is specifically not for any holiday, but for this one, it is more acceptable to use `в`-form:

- [В Пасху](http://www.newsru.ru/russia/24apr2011/nbh.html) около московских кладбищ нельзя будет купить спиртное. (See, this article is about that in a certain place, in Moscow, at certain time, on Easter, alcohol would be banned.)
- Но в Страстную Пятницу все идет наперекосяк, кто-то упорно мешает этому — взрывает и убивает людей Гарольда. (This has happened only once under some certain circumstances with these very guy).
- Домбровскис призывает в Рождество подумать о проделанной работе. (I guess, Mr. Dombrovkis suggest to do think about progress report only once, at this Christmas.)

The mnemonic formula for this case can be stated as `в [день, когда празднуется этот праздник] [где-то] [случилось что-то]`

And one more important thing, I'm talking only about tendencies in language, about the the way it is de-facto in modern Russian, but in all above mentioned cases you actually nevertheless can use both forms interchangeably:

- В сочельник у православных варили кутью, у католиков - бигилию. (Though `на` form is more frequent in this case).
- В Страстную пятницу не принято петь, гулять и веселиться.
- Я желаю тебе в это Рождество всего самого хорошего, здоровья тебе и твоей семье.

Comment: downvoter please explain.